# Python parsing *unknown format string to json or dict

Tags: python, python-3.x

The reason I say unknown is because it is being sent from an IOS 12 extension, I have no-hand in creating this format but lets just suppose there is no way I can do any formatting over there.

In Python what I receive is a string in the following format:

```
 {
   "body": '{\n  carrierName = "AT&T";\n dateRecieved = "2018-08-07 20:29:56 +0000";\n \n}'
 }
```

I want to know what this format {foo="bar"; top="long";} is called? It is what gets returned from iOS native Libraries so it has to be something; And is there any built-in way to parse it as a json or a dict. I can write my own parser for sure, but im looking for something built-in or something that exist in some generic library.

Comment: Lucky you, you get to build your own parser!

Comment: but is it really something? why would iOS generate something like that? 
i gave it a NSDictionary and it sent me back this, why??

Comment: That return format is a mess, I can't imagine it's some standard :/

Comment: The value of the `'body' item is probably JavaScript or some similar scripting language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have in the dictionary looks like JavaScript. Fortunately, Python can interpret JS via `py_mini_racer`. Install the module (say, with `pip`), create an instance of the interpreter:

```
from py_mini_racer import py_mini_racer
js = py_mini_racer.MiniRacer()

d = {
   "body": '{\n  carrierName = "AT&T";\n dateRecieved = "2018-08-07 20:29:56 +0000";\n \n}'
 }
```

Evaluate the expression and the variables, as needed:

```
js.eval(d['body'])
js.eval("carrierName")
#'AT&T'
js.eval("dateRecieved")
#'2018-08-07 20:29:56 +0000'
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm.  Correct me if I am wrong miniRacer.eval takes javscript statements in a string format as a parameter, but how did it know there would be statements wrapped inside {}? I have JS experience and this is not how you define objects in js (this will give you shorthand error which is basically solved by changing '=' to ':')

Comment: I believe in this case `{...}` defines not a map but a code block.

Answer (score 2):

parsing without the py_mini_racer. I could not install py_mini_racer on my
python 3.7

```
d = {
   "body": '{\n  carrierName = "AT&T";\n dateRecieved = "2018-08-07 20:29:56 +0000";\n \n}'
 }  

def parseD(d):
    import re
    def makeD(l): # make dict from 2 element list
        return dict([[s.strip().replace('"','') for s in l]])
    finalD = {}
    for di in [makeD(x) for x in [s.split('=') for s in re.findall(r'(\w+\s+=.*);', list(d.values())[0])]]:
        finalD.update(di)
    return finalD

parseD(d)   

{'carrierName': 'AT&T', 'dateRecieved': '2018-08-07 20:29:56 +0000'}

d = parseD(d)

d['carrierName']  

'AT&T'

d['dateRecieved']

'2018-08-07 20:29:56 +0000'
```

Comment: It has one problem: parsing is better and might work for others, but I had an issue with parsing that if any fields consist "" or , inside the property it would split on that too.

Comment: @tink, if you can give me the example of the problem fields I'll try to fix the script accordingly .

Comment: my bad I just saw that you are using regex and that should work as well..